# Use of the Well Ordering Principle in the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

Unlike a previous question that was closed on accounts of ambiguity, I perfectly understand the 'need' of the Well Ordering Principle in the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. What I do not understand is which is the set on which the well ordering principle is applied? Is it the set of numbers that cannot be written as a product of primes? Is the step intuitive?
The link contains the PDF that can be referred to for details on the proof:
[http://math.hawaii.edu/~lee/courses/fundamental.pdf](http://math.hawaii.edu/%7Elee/courses/fundamental.pdf)

Comment: In (1) of your link : By contradiction, suppose there is a counter-example to the FTA. Then there is a $least$ such counter-example, which they call $a.$

Answer (score 1):

The set of natural numbers which do not have a unique prime factorisation is either empty or it isn't. If it isn't empty, the WOP applies, and there is a smallest such number, $N$.

Now, it's not a question of having or not having a prime factorisation. It's easy to prove that a number has a prime factorisation. Any simple, naive factorisation algorithm is entirely deterministic and conclusive.

The issue is whether there can be more than one factorisation. And assuming $N$ as defined above exists, with multiple distinct prime factorisations, we can use Euclid's lemma to find a strictly smaller such number, contradicting the definition of $N$.

Comment: Thankyou @Arthur